# How to prove the foci of the ellipse must lie on the semimajor axes if the tack-and-string definition is true

Tags: geometry

[Hall & Higson](http://www.cems.uvm.edu/%7Etlakoba/AppliedUGMath/auxpaper_planets_HallHigson.pdf) define an ellipse as:

> Pick any two points.  These will be called the foci of the ellipse.   The  set  of  all  points  at  which  the sum of the distances to the two foci is some fixed number is an ellipse. Equivalently, affix two tacks to a board, tie each end of a string to a tack, and draw the curve created by a pencil which stretches the string taut.

Exercise 3(a) is to show that the foci of the ellipse must lie on the semimajor axes.  Why is this?

Comment: Ellipse, not eclipse. Ellipse is an oval shape. Eclipse is when one heavenly body crosses between two others leaving a shadow on one.

Comment: "if the tack-and-string definition is true" hasn't any meaning in mathematics; A definition is neither true nor false. You should have said: "Let us take the tack-and-string definition of the ellipse."...

Comment: This is obvious from the symmetry, isn't it? The figure drawn by the tack-and-string method is clearly symmetrical about the line joining the tacks.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the endpoints of the semiminor axis $A$ and $B$ are at equal distance from each foci $f_1$ and $f_2$, so the distance from $f_1$ to $A$ is the same that de distance from $f_1$ to B, therefore $f_1$ must lie on the perpendicular bisector of $A$ and $B$, which is the semimajor axis. The same argument works for $f_2$.

**Edit**: I think this is an easier argument: from the tack-and-string definition we get a triangle with fixed base $\overline{f_{1}f_{2}}$ and sides $a$, $b$ such that $a+b=\text{constant}$. The endpoints of the semiminor axis are the points where the height of this triangle is maximum, and the endpoints of the semimajor axis are the points where the height of this triangle is minimum, in this case the minimum is 0. If the height of the triangle is zero this means that the top vertex is collineal with the vertex of the base, and this implies that the foci are in the semimajor axis

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the argument. Why is the endpoints of the semiminor axis A and B are at equal distance from each foci f1 and f2?This doesn't seem to follow from the tack-and-string definition. It is also very clear taht semiminor and semimajor axis are perpendicular bisector to each other. I mean, yeah that is true but cannot be direcly followed from the definition.

Comment: I think this is an easier argument: from the tack-and-string definition we get a triangle with fixed base $\overline{f_{1}f_{2}}$ and sides $a$, $b$ such that $a+b=$constant. The endpoints of the semiminor axis are the points where the height of this triangle is maximum, and the endpoints of the semimajor axis are the points where the height of this triangle is minimum, in this case the minimum is $0$. If the height of the triangle is zero this means that the top vertex is collineal with the vertex of the base, and this implies that the foci are in the semimajor axis.

Comment: "the endpoints of the semimajor axis are the points where the height of this triangle is minimum" I don't see that as obvious?

Answer (score 0):

Let $F_1$, $F_2$ be the foci of the ellipse, $O$ its center (midpoint of $F_1F_2$).
As any point $P$ of the ellipse has the sum of its distances from the foci which is a fixed number $2a$, [from this property of the median](https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-prove-that-in-any-triangle-the-sum-of-two-sides-is-greater-than-twice-the-median-to-the-third-side) applied to triangle $PF_1F_2$ it follows that $PO<a$, unless $P$ lies on the line of the foci (for in that case triangle $PF_1F_2$ degenerates into a segment). If $P$ lies on the line of the foci, we have instead $PO=a$. Hence the points on the ellipse farther from the center, which are the endpoints of the major axis, lie on the line of the foci, as it was to be proved.